# So I am lost in creating classes, private/public variables, get/set functions, and more in Java

Tags: java, get, set, private, public

So this is the first part of my assignment:
Create a new java class called "House".

```
Add constructor without parameters and add a system out put of your choice
Add 4 Private Member Variables
    an integer that represents the number of rooms
    a String that represents the address
    a boolean that represents if the house is for sale
    a double that represents the value of the house
Add a Get and Set functions for ALL 4 member variables
```

In my house code I think this is the right way to do it:

```
public class House {
private int Rooms;
private String Address;
private double Value;
private boolean Sale;

public House() {
    System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR EXECUTED");
}

public void setRooms(int Rooms) {
    this.Rooms = Rooms;
}

public int getRooms () {
    return Rooms;
}

public void setAddress (String Address){
    this.Address = Address;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public void getValue(double Value) {
    this.Value = Value;
}

public double setValue() {
    return Value;
}

public void getSale(boolean Sale) {
    this.Sale = Sale;
}

public boolean getSale() {
    return Sale;
}
```

}

For the second part, which I'm more confused about, is says this:

```
Create a Main Class and add the static main function
Initialize Main and add a start function
In the start function create new House object
    Call all 4 Set functions
    Output all 4 Get Functions
        Example Output "The House has '4' rooms located at 'address' and is or is not for sale'
        If the house is for sale, out the value of the house
```

So I created the Main file and I think I have the start up correct but I don't know how to print it all out. This is what I at least have so far:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] arg) {
}

private void start() {
    House rooms = new House ();


}
```

}

I definitely do not want the answer, just some pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the instructions, I don't think you need to create a separate `Main` class. I think when it says 'Initialize Main' it just means add the `main` method to the `House` class.

Additionally, the way you have it now is not going to work properly. `start()` will not be able to be called from the `main` method, since `main` is static and `start` is not.

My feeling is that the best way to go about it would be to put `main` and `start` in the `House` class. Then, you can initialize an instance of `House` in the `main` method, and then call `start` on that instance. From there, `start` can perform the rest of the instructions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Best practice would be to keep the POJO class and implementation separate.

Comment: I agree with you, and that's what I would do myself, but it looked from the instructions that it should be kept simple. All it says is 'Initialize Main and add a start function' which to me indicates leaving it in all in one file.

Comment: From how you set out the matter, it appears that you are completely fasting in OOP.